# Extracting more than one Video using mp4box?

Tags: video, mp4

I have one Container Stream which includes more than 1 video. means it has multiple video in it. so i want to extract those video in elementary stream. so can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP4Box -raw val path -out ele_path.

val denotes that how many videos you want to extract which are located at val index.